# Material & Colours Look Different in Viewport Material Preview & Rendered Modes

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, 3d-view

newbie here... taking advantage of my covid lockdown to learn realistic 3D modelling. I'm doing the Youtube intro series done by Blender Guru, where you create a donut and a coffee mug and having a blast.

Problem: My donut icing and sprinkles no longer render right. In the Material Preview view, they both look as intended (white icing with a pink gloss, colorful sprinkles randomized), but in Rendered mode and after I've done a full render the sprinkles lose their random colour and the icing changes colour too (ends up a flat blue with the original colors of my spinkles that I made for the particle effect).

When I completed the donut, it rendered fine. Somewhere along the line in creating my coffee mug I've done something that has impacted the way the donut renders.

Attempted Solutions:

- I've tried to redo the shading view options and recreate the randomized colors
- I've deleted the lighting and put in new lighting (my understanding is that lighting is one of the major differences between Rendered and Material Preview
- I've googled for solutions but haven't found anything of note to try.

Here is the blender file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/uuacijw1dts6xbo/Coffee%20Mug%20%26%20Donut.blend?dl=0

Any ideas on what I need to do to get my icing looking all nice and glossy pink and my random coloured sprinkles working in my render?

Thanks!

**LEFT**: Rendered mode (Colors are all wrong)           **RIGHT**: Material Preview (**DESIRED LOOK!**)
[image: LEFT: Rendered mode (Colors are all wrong) RIGHT: Material Preview (Desired look works fine)]

Shading View settings for Sprinkles
[image: Shading View settings for Sprinkles]

Shading View settings for Icing 
[image: Shading View settings for Icing]

Comment: It caused by the SubSurfaceScattering. Do you really need it?

Comment: The subsurface scattering gives my white icing a bit of a pink color. Similar effects on the sprinkles, but less visible.

Comment: If the subsurface scattering is rendering properly in the Material Preview viewport mode, why isn't it rendering properly in the Rendered viewport more?

Comment: Turns out it was the subsurface radius was too high...

Comment: Material Preview is not properly, because it's not affected by the lights.

Comment: thanks for the question, same i needed to look this up